# Why were the addicts periodically taken by the "bad guys" to the camp in the desert?

Tags: plot-explanation, bosch

Why were the addicts periodically taken by the "bad guys" to the camp in the desert in the fifth season of *Bosch*? There doesn't seem to be any reason stated or implied.

Answer (score 4):

### Because they could be contained and controlled there.

Recall, these are *addicts* and, by their nature, erratic. By removing them from their normal locales and isolating them in the desert, the bad guys not only have the addicts out of sight but it also leaves the addicts nowhere to go.

Contrast this with locking them up in a warehouse or abandoned house. If they escape they are immediately available to law enforcement.

In the desert, they can't escape and they are entirely dependent on the bad guys for their next fix.

As raised in the comments, the timeline of Bosch's interactions in the camp is somewhat unclear. He only goes there once but Elizabeth mentions that she is familiar with it.

This would imply that Elizabeth has been there a number of times but the time gap between Bosch's arrival and previous interactions with Elizabeth (in Narcotics Anonymous) and elsewhere seems *fluid* (on a single watch through).

So it's possible that the inmates of the desert location are given some freedom until they are needed by the bad guys and then put back into "rotation" for a set period of time.

Comment: But there's still extended periods where they continue their normal lives in between.

Comment: Is there? Do we see that? I don't recall that.

Comment: What I mean is, they aren't held captive there for the rest of their lives, only for a the few days it takes for them to travel around the state cashing in their receipts. After that they get sent home again. That's how Bosch first meats Elizabeth and the other guy afterall, in his house and in the AAA (or whatever the painkiller equivalent) meeting. Elizabeth also strongly implies she's been at the camp various times.

Comment: Though, I guess the answer still makes sense insofar as it's still easier to fly/drive them around the state from the camp whenever they do a receipt run every few weeks.

Comment: Hmmm....interesting, that's not the way I saw it. I was under the impression that Elizabeth in NA was before the desert trips and the desert "option" was her "final destination". That could bear a re-watch.

Comment: When Bosch asks her where they're going she says "to hell" or something, implying she knows where they go. She also talks like she's acquainted with the place and its "customs" when they have a moment talking at the camp.

Comment: But...your interpretation is interesting and worth a consideration (or even its own question), too. If anything, it might be worth adding to the answer, since I think the question, calling it "periodically", might not have considered that either.